# Excel VBA: Coloring cells under multiple conditions

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting, vba

I am currently altering some prewritten code, so I created a test dummyfile. I am experiencing misbehaviours, where I am unable to find the culprit of. First of all here is my sample Excel datasheet:

```
Issue Date  Maturity    Status  ISIN            Price
19/01/2018  06/01/2020  Issued  XS2375645421    97
25/01/2013  01/01/2020  Issued  XS0879579182    88
12/01/2015  07/01/2020  Issued  XS4158674165    92
20/01/2018  05/01/2020  Issued  XS5458614653    98
31/01/2018  03/01/2020  Traded  XS5445656466    87
06/02/2018  02/01/2020  In Sub  XS1515113535    99
```

Furthermore, you'll find my code used below:

```
Sub Button1_Click()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim count As Integer
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
'if wb is other than the active workbook
wb.Activate
ws.Select


'Colorizing The ISIN with the following 3 conditions:

'1.) Issue Date <= today
'2.) Issue Date + 14d > today
'3.) Price <= 98
'So in summary the conditions mean that today has to be in between the Issue Date
'and 14 days after the Issue Date and the price has to be lower than 98

count = 0
Do While CDate(ws.Cells(2 + count, 1).Value) <= CDate(Now()) And _
ws.Cells(2 + count, 5).Value <= 98 And _
CDate(DateAdd("d", 14, ws.Cells(2 + count, 1).Value)) > CDate(Now())

count = count + 1

ws.Range("D" & count + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 50, 50)

Loop



End Sub
```

The code works partially, the first ISIN value gets colored, however afterwards if not all conditions are met, the loop suddenly stops. If it would continue, the ISIN in row 5 should also be colored, because all conditions are satisfied. See screenshot below:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards

Comment: It stops because that is how you have set up the loop. Why not use a For loop?

Comment: why don't you use conditional formatting for that? There is no need to use VBA. Add a new conditional formatting rule with this formula `=AND(A2<TODAY(),E2<=98,A2+14>TODAY())` to cell D2 and copy format down to the other cells in D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The issue

Your loop stops because it runs only until **one** of the 3 conditions is false. And your condition

```
CDate(DateAdd("d", 14, ws.Cells(2 + count, 1).Value)) > CDate(Now())
```

is false for the second data row already. That means everything after the second row is skipped.

---

#### VBA Solution

So you need a loop that loops through **all** data rows and checks with an `if` statement if the conditions are fulfilled. If true then color it if not move on to the next row.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim count As Long 'we need to use Long instead of Integer
                      'Excel has more rows than Integer can handle
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'ThisWorkbook = the wb where this code runs .. is better than
                          'ActiveWorkbook = any workbook that is in focus at the moment
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'if wb is other than the active workbook
    wb.Activate 'this is not needed to run the code
    ws.Select 'this is not needed to run the code

    count = 0
    Do While ws.Cells(2 + count, 1).Value <> vbNullString 'do while first cell contains data
        If CDate(ws.Cells(2 + count, 1).Value) <= CDate(Now()) And _
           ws.Cells(2 + count, 5).Value <= 98 And _
           CDate(DateAdd("d", 14, ws.Cells(2 + count, 1).Value)) > CDate(Now()) Then

            'color it
            ws.Range("D" & count + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 50, 50)
        End If

        count = count + 1 'next row
    Loop
End Sub
```

Note: Have a look at the comments I made which improve the code.

---

#### Conditional Formatting Solution

As an alternative to VBA I suggest to use conditional formatting.

Add a new conditional formatting rule with this formula

```
=AND(A2<TODAY(),E2<=98,A2+14>TODAY())
```

to cell D2 and copy format down to the other cells in column D.
Conditional formatting changes instantly as you change data values and you don't need to run a VBA code for this.

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you so much, this was really helpful. However it also colors the column title (ISIN), how do I get rid of that?

Comment: Never mind, found the issue, did not delete my previous colorings, sorry.. Thanks any way for your solution, really appreciate it!